# handlebarjs print map as a table

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js

I have json:

```
   "Fields":{  
      "AAA":0.7391,
      "BBB":0.1234,
   }
```

I would like it to render like:

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Fields</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>AAA</td>
    <td>0.7391</td> 

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>BBB</td>
    <td>0.1234</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

How can I achieve this using [handlebarjs](https://handlebarsjs.com/)?

Comment: Have a look on block expressions: https://handlebarsjs.com/#block-expressions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is iterating over one object properties with handlebar, you can use the code below as a template :

```
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Fields</th>
  </tr>
{{#each Fields}}
  <tr>
    <td>{{@key}}</td>
    <td>{{this}}</td>
  </tr>
{{/each}}
</table>
```